# Использование частиц НЕ и/или НИ

Tags: частица-не

Подскажите, как правильно написать: "воспитал не одну плеяду учеников" или "воспитал ни одну плеяду учеников"?

Answer (score 3):

Частица ***ни*** усиливает отрицание, то есть обычно ей сопутствует частица ***не***. У вас отрицательная частица единственная. Правильно:

- *воспитал **не** одну плеяду учеников*

Но:

- ***не*** воспитал **ни** одного ученика